# Bootstrap overiding jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

I am new to mvc5 and bootstrap and applying an jquery plugin in but the style is not geting updated. Is there anyway that i can prevent the bootstrap overiding?

the code am using in view is as follows

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable();
    });
</script>
```

the files that i am binding are as follows

```
<script src="~/Content/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.min.css" type="text/css"> </script>
<script src="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" type="text/css"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: what is overriding ? any css style from bootstrap? can you explain bit more?

Comment: @user3662273 The js script style wasnt loading in the page. It resolved by binding all the js files after bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js in layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js script style wasnt loading in the page. It resolved by binding all the js files after bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js in layout.cshtml –